# A class that can accept variable function references of unknown signature

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

I'd like to create a class, than when instantiated, accepts a variable number of function references that don't have signatures known beforehand.  Here's an example that almost does what I want:

```
// To show the function refs being used 
void p(int arg) { cout << "int " << arg << endl; }
void p(string arg) { cout << "string " << arg << endl; }
void p(int arg1, int arg2) { cout<<"int/int "<<arg1<<arg2<<endl; }
void p(int arg1, string arg2) { cout<<"int/string "<<arg1<<arg2<<endl; }

class foo {
    public:
    // CTOR takes variadic function refs 
    template <typename... Args>
    foo(Args... args) { p(args()...); }
    // "args()..." requires supplied functions to take no parameters 
    // but makes no requirement on their return values. 
};

// Using lambdas, but free functions, std::bind(), etc. work too
foo i([]{return 1;});              // prints "int 1" 
foo s([]{return string("one");});  // prints "string one" 
foo b([]{return 2;},
      []{return string("two");});  // prints "int/string 2two"
```

What I can't see how to fix this so that the functions supplied as arguments are not evaluated in the constructor.  I'd like the call to `p(args()...)` to be done later, by another method in `foo`.  This is why foo can't be created as simply as `foo i(1)`: the argument function(s) need to be called later, and multiple times, not just once when the object is created (and they'd be more complex than just returning a constant).

The problem seems to come down to saving references to the constructor parameters to be called later, when the class doesn't know how many or what signature those parameters will have.  Somehow the arguments need to be part of a class template and not just a constructor template, but how?

If the functions passed all had the same signature, then one could use a class template with a non-type parameters and supply the functions as template arguments:

```
template <int (&...Arg)()>
class bar {
    public:
    bar() { p(Arg()...); }
    other() { p(Arg()...); } // Use in any method
};

int one() { return 1; }
int two() { return 2; }
bar<one> bi;       // Prints "int 1"
bar<one, two> bii; // Prints "int/int 12"
```

But this requires all the arguments be functions that return int and also doesn't work with lambdas as they can't be template arguments.

Comment: I read this and think Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lambda and a `std::function` to do that.
Note that a lambda can capture a parameters pack and (let me say) unpack it later.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

void p(int arg) { std::cout << "int " << arg << std::endl; }
void p(std::string arg) { std::cout << "string " << arg << std::endl; }
void p(int arg1, int arg2) { std::cout<<"int/int "<<arg1<<arg2<<std::endl; }
void p(int arg1, std::string arg2) { std::cout<<"int/string "<<arg1<<arg2<<std::endl; }

class foo {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    foo(Args... args): func{[args...](){ p(args()...); }} {}

    void operator()() { func(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> func;
};

int main() {
    // create your objects...
    foo i([]{return 1;});
    foo s([]{return std::string("one");});
    foo b([]{return 2;}, []{return std::string("two");});
    // ... and use them later
    i();
    s();
    b();
}
```

Comment: I see, the lambda lets one pack/unpack the parameter pack into a class member whose type is not dependent on the parameter pack.

Comment: My real use is more complex, and the parameter pack is just part of the arguments to a function, e.g. `make_shared<ObjType>("name", args()..., index++)`  The lambda can't capture _just_ the `args()...` part like I'd like.  The solution seems to be to expand the lambda until it produces a complete expression whose signature doesn't depend on the parameter pack.  Such as `[=](string n, int i){return make_shared<ObjType>(n, args()..., i);}` and adjusting `func` to match.

Comment: @TrentP Well, answers are strictly based on questions. I cannot know what's the real problem, so I cannot say what's the best solution for it. I'm sorry.